# How do I run os.walk in parallel in Python?

Tags: python

I wrote a simple app in Java that takes a list of paths and generates a file with all the file paths under that original list.

If I have paths.txt that has:

```
c:\folder1\
c:\folder2\
...
...
c:\folder1000\
```

My app runs the recursive function on each path multithreaded, and returns a file with all the file paths under these folders.

Now I want to write this app in Python.

I've written a simple app that uses `os.walk()` to run through a given folder and print the filepaths to output.

Now I want to run it in parallel, and I've seen that Python has some modules for this:
multithreaded and multiprocessing.

What is the best what to do this? And within that way, how is it performed?

Comment: What do you expect from a multi-threaded traversal? Since you are IO bound a single-threaded traversal will be as fast as two threads sharing the IO load among both threads....so what do you expect to win  from going multi-threaded?

Comment: running the same in java turned out to be faster when running multithreaded. some of the paths are network paths, so maybe running multithreaded optimizes the network traffic.

Comment: Using the multiprocessing module is likely more appropriate here over the threading module.

Comment: @AndreasJung : I agree, but how would you do it?

Comment: One issue with Python's os.walk is that if you have directories with lots of files, you'll read a lot into memory as it iterates on one directory worth of info at a time.  I have found just switching over to a recursive os.listdir generator works much better than using os.walk.

Answer (score 27):

Here is a *multiprocessing* solution:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue as Queue
import os

def explore_path(path):
    directories = []
    nondirectories = []
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        if os.path.isdir(fullname):
            directories.append(fullname)
        else:
            nondirectories.append(filename)
    outputfile = path.replace(os.sep, '_') + '.txt'
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
        for filename in nondirectories:
            print >> f, filename
    return directories

def parallel_worker():
    while True:
        path = unsearched.get()
        dirs = explore_path(path)
        for newdir in dirs:
            unsearched.put(newdir)
        unsearched.task_done()

# acquire the list of paths
with open('paths.txt') as f:
    paths = f.read().split()

unsearched = Queue()
for path in paths:
    unsearched.put(path)

with Pool(5) as pool:
    for i in range(5):
        pool.apply_async(parallel_worker)

unsearched.join()
print('Done')
```

Comment: That would parallelize the work you do, but not the walking itself.

Comment: @static_rtti Why would that matter?  The point of parallelization is to speed-up the task as a whole.   More fine-grained parallelization is typically more expensive than course-grained.   Also, it would require that you break the *os.walk()* abstraction and essentially rewrite some of its code (throwing-away the benefits of having the library in the first place).  In addition, there isn't much benefit to parallelizing the walking itself because that is an I/O bound operation.

Comment: @static_rtti One other thought.  The OP stated in the comments that he is using multiple network drives that can run in parallel.   So the speed benefit comes from running multiple walk tasks in parallel.  If you tried to parallelize the walking itself, there would be no benefit  because the read/write arm on a single drive can only do one thing at a time.

Comment: even on a single network drive, it can speed things up significantly because of network latency. Saying that fine-grained parallelism slows things down as a generality is just plain wrong, the reality is that it depends.

Comment: @static_rtti While you are right that it depends on the exact circumstances whether parallelization of the walking itself would be beneficial, a course grained parallelization of multiple walking tasks over the network on different drives almost *for sure* provides a speed-up, by experience. Have you ever done a `du -s *` or a `find ...` on multiple network drives? You will never saturate your network interface with such commands, and they run entirely independent through different systems (e.g. NFS connections).

Comment: I believe you got the os.walk wrong in the second code snippet: each directory will be processed multiple times (os.walk is recursive).

Comment: os.walk() yields once before it recurses.  The *break* makes sure it never gets to the recursive stage.  The code is correct.  If it bugs you, then manually split os.listdir() into directories and files using os.path.isdir().  That is what os.walk() does internally.  The OP's question has been fairly answered.  Now, it it time for you to do your duty.

Comment: In my case, I stuck forever in `unsearched.join()`. Replacing `JoinableQueue ` by `Manager().Queue()` solved the problem. https://gist.github.com/samuelsh/a8be5bc93fcd7ff256c9

Comment: is it guaranteed that this code will NOT recheck symlinks, dir junction, and something like that? It would take forever to check a forever loop because of junctions.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't run `with open('files.txt') as f: f.split()`

Answer (score 6):

This is a pattern for threads in python which has been useful to me. I'm not sure if threading is going to increase your performance due to the way threads work in CPython though.

```
import threading
import Queue
import os

class PathThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def printfiles(self, p):
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
            for f in files:
                print path + "/" + f

    def run(self):
        while True:
            path = self.queue.get()
            self.printfiles(path)
            self.queue.task_done()

# threadsafe queue
pathqueue = Queue.Queue()
paths = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

# spawn threads
for i in range(0, 5):
    t = PathThread(pathqueue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

# add paths to queue
for path in paths:
    pathqueue.put(path)

# wait for queue to get empty
pathqueue.join()
```

Comment: A threading approach to parallelization is likely going to be counter-productive.  Python's global interpreter lock will prevent any two threads from running concurrently.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Not for IO, though :)

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Plainly wrong in this case, sorry. You are repeating the big lie of the GIL.  Blocking operations, I/O are not held up by the GIL, and there are many cases where processing occurs outside of the GIL. Don't get me wrong, GIL sucks, but it doesn't make multithreading in Python worthless.

Answer (score 1):

Even threading can be pretty helpful for directory traversal. I use the following code for traversing a SharePoint tree, getting a pretty significant speedup for about 50 threads.
This particular program returns (path, data) pairs for all xml files in a directory structure, and can be simply expanded for your use.
(This is cut and pasted from my program; some additional editing is needed.)

```
#unique string for error passing error messages
ERROR = '\xffERROR\xff'

class ScanWorker(threading.Thread):
    """Worker class for scanning directory structures.
    pathQueue: queue for pathnames of directories
    resultQueue: results of processFile, pairs of (path, data) to be updated
    """
    lock = threading.Lock()
    dirCount = 0
    def __init__(self, pathQueue, resultQueue):
        self.pathQueue = pathQueue
        self.resultQueue = resultQueue
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        """Worker thread.
        Get a directory, process it, and put new directories on the
        queue."""
        try:
            while True:
                self.processDir(self.pathQueue.get())
                self.pathQueue.task_done()
        except Exception as e:
            #pass on exception to main thread
            description = traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())
            description.insert(0,
                "Error in thread {}:\n".format(
                    threading.current_thread().name))
            self.resultQueue.put((ERROR, description))
            self.pathQueue.task_done()

    def processDir(self, top):
        """Visit a directory
        Call self.processFile on every file, and queue the directories.
        """
        #Wait and retry a few times in case of network errors.
        #SharePoint is not reliable, gives errors for no reason
        for retryCount in range(30):
            try:
                names = listdir(top)
                break
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno in (2,22):
                    lastError = e
                    print(end="L", flush=True)
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    raise
        else:
            print("List: too many retries")
            raise lastError
        #it is not important to worry about race conditions here
        self.__class__.dirCount += 1
        #process contents
        for name in names:
            if isdir(join(top, name)): self.pathQueue.put(join(top, name))
            else: self.processFile(join(top, name))

    def processFile(self, path):
        """Get XML file.
        """
        #only xml files
        if not path.lower().endswith('.xml'): return
        filemtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(getmtime(path))
        #SharePoint is not reliable, gives errors for no reason; just retry
        for retryCount in range(30):
            try:
                data = open(path,'rb').read()
                break
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno in (2,22):
                    lastError = e
                    print(end="R", flush=True)
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    raise
        else:
            print("Read: too many retries")
            raise lastError
        self.resultQueue.put((path, data))

class Scanner:
    """Interface to the ScanWorkers
    Sharepoint is pretty fast compared to its delay and handles 50 workers well
    Make sure you only create one instance of Scanner!
    """
    def __init__(self, workers):
        #don't restrict the path queue length; this causes deadlock
        #we use a LIFO queue to get more depth-first like search
        #reducing average queue length and hopefully improving server caching
        self.pathQueue = queue.LifoQueue()
        #this is the output queue to the main thread
        self.resultQueue = queue.Queue(5)
        self.workers = workers
        #start workers
        for i in range(workers):
            t = ScanWorker(self.pathQueue, self.resultQueue)
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()

    def startWorkers(self, path):
        #add counter
        self.added = 0
        #and go
        self.pathQueue.put(path)

    def processResult(self, wait=True):
        """Get an element from the result queue, and add to the zip file."""
        path, data = self.resultQueue.get(block=wait)
        if path==ERROR:
            #process gave alarm; stop scanning
            #pass on description
            raise ScanError(data)
        <do whatever you want to do with the file>
        self.resultQueue.task_done()
        self.added += 1

#main
try:
    #set up
    scanner = Scanner(threads)
    scanner.startWorkers(rootpath)
    pathQueue, resultQueue = scanner.pathQueue, scanner.resultQueue
    #scanner is rolling; wait for it to finish
    with pathQueue.all_tasks_done:
        while pathQueue.unfinished_tasks:
            #tasks are still running
            #process results
            while True:
                try: scanner.processResult(wait=False)
                except queue.Empty: break
            #no new files found; check if scanner is ready
            done = pathQueue.all_tasks_done.wait(timeout=1)
            if not done:
                #Not yet; print something while we wait
                print(
                    "\rProcessed {} files from {} directories [{} {}]  "
                    .format(
                        scanner.added,
                        ScanWorker.dirCount,
                        pathQueue.unfinished_tasks,
                        resultQueue.unfinished_tasks,
                    ), end='\r')
    #just to make sure everybody is ready: join the path queue
    pathQueue.join()
    #process remaining of result queue
    while resultQueue.unfinished_tasks: scanner.processResult(wait=True)
    #go to new line to prevent overwriting progress messages
    print()
except ScanError as e:
    print()
    print(*e.args[0], end='')
    print("Process interrupted.")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nProcess interrupted.")
print()
```

Comment: what are the modules you imported?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```py
import os
import concurrent.futures
from time import time
from tqdm import tqdm


def _listdir(folder):
    return folder, os.listdir(folder)

class walk:

    def __init__(self, folder: str, max_workers: int = os.cpu_count()):
        self.folders = [folder]
        self.max_workers = max_workers
        self.futures = []

    def __iter__(self):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.max_workers) as executor:
            while len(self.folders):
                folder = self.folders.pop(0)
                future = executor.submit(_listdir, folder)
                self.futures.append(future)

            while self.futures:
                for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(self.futures):
                    filenames = []
                    folders = []

                    folder, files_or_folders = future.result()
                    self.futures = [f for f in self.futures if f != future]

                    for file_or_folder in files_or_folders:
                        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, file_or_folder)):
                            filenames.append(file_or_folder)
                        else:
                            folders.append(file_or_folder)
                            self.folders.append(os.path.join(folder, file_or_folder))

                    yield folder, folders, filenames

                    while len(self.folders) and len(self.futures) <= self.max_workers * 2:
                        folder = self.folders.pop(0)
                        future = executor.submit(_listdir, folder)
                        self.futures.append(future)
        return


t0 = time()
num_files = 0
for root, directories, filenames in tqdm(walk("..."), smoothing=0):
    num_files += len(filenames)
print(time() - t0, num_files)
```