# Using Pool with Queue in the Python multiprocessing module

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to use the multiprocessing module to speed up traversing a directory structure.  First I did some research and found this Stack Overflow thread:

[How do I run os.walk in parallel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920490/how-do-i-run-os-walk-in-parallel-in-python)

However, when I tried to adapt the code in the thread, I kept on running into a problem.  Here is a little script I wrote to just test out Pool and figure out how it works.:

```
import os

from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue as Queue

def scan():
    print "Hi!"
    while True:
        print "Inside loop"
        directory = unsearched.get()
        print "Got directory"
        unsearched.task_done()
        print "{0}".format(directory)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Put those directories on the queue
    unsearched = Queue()
    top_dirs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    for d in top_dirs:
        unsearched.put(d)
    print unsearched

    # Scan the directories
    processes = 1
    pool = Pool(processes)
    for i in range(processes):
        print "Process {0}".format(i)
        pool.apply_async(scan)

    # Block until all the tasks are done
    unsearched.join()
    print 'Done'
```

What is happening is that the script goes inside of the loop inside of the scan function and just sits there:

```
PS C:\Test> python .\multiprocessing_test.py
<multiprocessing.queues.JoinableQueue object at 0x000000000272F630>
Process 0
Hi!
Inside loop
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually runs fine for me on Linux, but does hang on Windows. This is because on Windows, everything inside the `if __name__ ...` guard doesn't get executed in the child process, which of course includes defining `unsearched`. That means that `scan` is throwing an exception when it tries to used `unsearched`, but that exception is never consume in the parent, so you don't see the Traceback show up in the CLI. Instead, it just hangs.

To make this work on Windows and Linux, you can use the `initializer`/`initargs` keyword arguments when you create the `Pool` to make `unsearched` in scope in the child:

```
def initializer(q):
    global unsearched
    unsearched = q
```

...

Then replace your old `Pool` call with this:

```
pool = Pool(processes, initializer=initializer, initargs=(unsearched,))
```

Comment: Great!  It works!  Is there a way to see a Traceback from a child process?

Comment: @ChristopherSpears Normally you would get the traceback when you tried to fetch the result of the `apply_async` call. If you store the result of each of those in a list and call `result.get()` on each prior to calling `unsearched.join() `, I think you'll be able to receive the exception and not hang forever.